# итерация генератора в Питоне

Tags: python, генераторы

Я сейчас изучаю генераторы Питона и у меня возник вопрос. Не ругайтесь сильно если он глупый. Суть:
Я решил создать генератор (в учебных целях), объект которого после прохождения цикла в цикле for, снова будет готов проходить цикл for без создания нового объекта. Как я понимаю, цикл for завершает свою работу после улавливания исключения StopIteration. Поэтому моя функция генератора имеет вид:

```
    def gen():
        n = 0
        while True:
            yield n+1
            n += 1
            if n > 2:
                n = 0
                raise StopIteration

g = gen()
for i in g:
    print(i)
```

Но в этом случае при первом же прохождении for не улавливает исключение SropItaration.

На выходе:

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 8, in gen
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    for i in g:
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Почему? Как пофиксить?

Comment: Генератор не должен явно выбрасывать StopIteration. Если нужно завершить итерацию, просто сделайте return из генератора. StopIteration должен выбрасывать только "голый" итератор на классах с методами `__iter__` и `__next__`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но в этом случае следующий вызов for ничего не дает.

Comment: Какой следующий for? Если вы второй раз пытаетесь пройтись циклом по g, то это не сработает, потому что итератор в переменной g уже "исчерпался". Создайте новый итератор и итерируйтесь по нему.

Comment: то есть невозможно перед выходом (return) из функции обнулить "исчерпавшийся" итератор, чтобы вызывать for с этим же объектом генератора g?

Comment: Нельзя, итераторы - одноразовые объекты. Можно только создать новый итератор.

Comment: Извините за назойливость, но хочу докопаться до истины.
Как же тогда итератор обнуляется в, например, списках? Ведь я могу использовать один и   тот же экземпляр объекта списка в цикле   for сколь угодно раз и он всегда будет "отрабатывать" от начала до конца.

Comment: Есть две большие разницы - итератор и итерируемый объект (iterable). Итерируемый объект (как тот же список) можно обходить много раз. При попытке итерации по объекту у него вызывается метод `__iter__`, у итерируемых объектов он каждый раз возвращает новый итератор. У итераторов этот метод возвращает сам объект.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle